# BT5 multiroom connectivity

Tags: qtbluetooth, bluetooth-5

I would like to broadcast audio to multiroom devices using BT5 instead of wifi. I am a DJ/Sound engineer but have spoken to several engineers that have not been able to solve this issue.I would appreciate anyone chiming in to resolve this issue.
Sincerely
Darrin

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is simple: Bluetooth 5.0 does not natively support broadcasting audio to a random number of devices at the same time.